# Evaluating the Limit of De Mere's Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, limits

I'm stuck on a problem that involves de Mere's problem (or de Mere's paradox). For those who don't know, de Mere's problem is essentially the following: "If I roll $n$ dice $4\times6^{n-1}$ times, what is the probability that all the dice show a six?"

The problem I'm stuck on is the following:

> Use the Calculus 1 definition of the constant $e$ to find the limit of de Mere's problem.

For ease, the definition of $e$ is below:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}$$

Here's what I have so far:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-(1-\frac{1}{6^n})^{4\times6^{n-1}})=\lim_{n\to\infty}1-\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{6^n})^{4\times6^{n-1}}=1-\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\frac{1}{6^n})^{4\times6^{n-1}}$$

which is admittedly not much. My basic intuition tells me that the limit should approach zero, as raising a number less than one to a positive number will decrease the number. I don't see how I can incorporate the definition of $e$ into this; the only types of problems that I know can possibly reduce to something involving $e$ are Inclusion-Exclusion problems, and I don't think this problem is of that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use the other definition of $e$, namely
\begin{align*}
e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n.
\end{align*}
Straight from the above definition we obtain
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1-\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\Big[\Big(1+\frac{1}{n-1}\Big)^{n-1}\Big]^{\frac{n}{n-1}}}=\frac{1}{e}
\end{align*} 
and consequently
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(1-\frac{1}{6^n}\Big)^{4\times6^{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\Big(1-\frac{1}{6^n}\Big)^{6^{n}}\Big]^{\frac{4}{6}}=e^{-\frac{2}{3}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: $(1-1/n)=(n-1)/n=1/(n/(n-1))=1/(1+1/(n-1))$